# How to get the attributes to show into the HeadlessUI dialog

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, headless-ui

I'm just learning to use nextJs and having trouble using nextJs. I'm trying to get the title of the attribute put to the button and the data attribute will be placed in the headlessui dialog.

this is the code i use

```
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'

export default function MainPages() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

  function openModal(event) {
    setIsOpen(true)
    // document.getElementsByClassName("dialog-title").innerHTML = event.target.dataset.title;
    document.querySelector(".dialog-title").innerHTML = event.target.dataset.title;
    // document.querySelectorAll(".dialog-title").innerHTML = event.target.dataset.title;
    console.log(event.target.dataset.title);
  }

  return (
    <button
          type="button"
          data-title="HELLO WORLD"
          onClick={openModal}
        >
      Open dialog
    </button>

    <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog>
        <Transition.Child></Transition.Child>
        <Transition.Child>
          <Dialog.Panel>
            <Dialog.Title as="h1" className="dialog-title"></Dialog.Title>
          </Dialog.Panel>
        </Transition.Child>
      </Dialog> 
  </Transition> 
  );
}
```

how to get the button's **data-title** attribute and put the attribute into the dialog's **.dialog-title**?

I use the .tsx file format and I'm confused because I'm studying, maybe friends here can help with my problem.